# How to get the actual failing reason for customPairing.PairAsync?

Tags: c#, uwp, wifi-direct

Working in c# Wifi Direct Windows to Android Device pairing. Getting below result status "Failed".

```
result = await customPairing.PairAsync(DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly);
```

How can I get the detail information and reason for failing?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191412/deviceinformation-pairasync-not-working-in-wpf)?

Comment: @TimothyStepanski I am using similar approach, but I am interested to know the detail cause log.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get the actual failing reason for customPairing.PairAsync?

I'm afraid you can't get the detail info from `PairAsync` method, currently UWP has not provided the detail reason when paired failed. You could only get limited state explain [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicepairingresultstatus?view=winrt-19041#fields). It means **An unknown failure occurred** If the state is `Failed`. If you do want this feature please feel free post your requirement with windows feed back hub app.
By the way you may check if system Event Viewer contains such failed reason.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's annoying when you cant get the root cause. I will check what you suggested.

Comment: Yep, I could empathize, please feel free post your requirement and help us improve UWP  experience.